# "this" value that can not be converted to type Ui

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-apps

I'm using Google Apps Script and I'm trying to re-use code that calls render so that I don't have to re-type everything. I'm running into an issue that seems to relate to "this" getting transformed.

Code:

```
function render(displayMedium, template_name) {

    var js = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('javascript.html');
    var css = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('stylesheet.html');


    var t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(template_name);
    js.config = config;
    css.config = config;
    t.config = config;
    t.appProperties = appProperties;
    js.appProperties = appProperties;
    t.jsBlock = js.evaluate().getContent();
    t.cssBlock = css.evaluate().getContent();

    displayMedium(
      HtmlService
      .createHtmlOutput(t.evaluate())
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE)

};

function renderSidebar(){
  var displayMedium = DocumentApp.getUi().showSidebar;
  var template_name = "app.html";
  render(displayMedium, template_name);
};
```

And when I call renderSidebar() the error I get is as follows:

[ERROR: InternalError: Method "showSidebar" was invoked with [object Object] as "this" value that can not be converted to type Ui.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work if you bind the function to the UI object:

```
var displayMedium = DocumentApp.getUi().showSidebar.bind(DocumentApp.getUi());
```

When you grab that function reference, then unless you do something like the above the runtime will (or might; it clearly does here) invoke the function with some other `this` value (depends on the API).